# ReportServer Execution Log look before 2 months

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, logging, reporting-services

is there a way that I can look into the report server execution log file before two months? I would like to dispose a reportserver database and want to see which report is last run. Sql Server Execution log file only stores for 2 months,but I want to see the log before that.I am using the Microsoft Sql Server 2005. 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is no... As you've seen this is 60 days by default; after that SSRS will delete any old entries from its internal `ExecutionLog` table.

What you can do is change this default:

[Server Properties (Logging Page)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188457%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

This is not much use for your existing data but at least this might let you collect the information you need from now on.